# Getting Arraylist IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

Consider this code:

```
for(int i=0;i <n;i++)
{
    idx=transactions.get(row).size();
    c.add(transactions.get(row).get(idx));
}
```

This is my code. I am getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

for the line  `c.add(transactions.get(row).get(idx))`. What is the problem?

Comment: You have omitted ***all*** the relevant details: the definition of `transactions` and its `get()` method, the definition of the class of objects returned by `transactions.get()` and how it implements its own `get()`, code showing how `transactions` was populated, the values of `row` and `idx`... `i` isn't even used inside the loop.

Comment: Just a guess: Java uses zero-based indexing. You set `idx` to the number of elements, but valid indices go from 0 to `size() - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The index of the first element is 0. The size of the collection is a number which is one more than the last index. E.g, if the collection is of size 5, the last index is 4. What you probably want to do is this:

```
idx = transactions.get(row).size() - 1;
```

Curious about why indexing starts at 0? Read this fine article by Dijsktra: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html